# Is there any convenient way to check if a DOM element is `$compile`d in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-compile

I'm trying to integrate some plain JavaScript library with AngularJS, in which I need to manually `$compile` some DOM elements. I'm doing the compilation like this:

```
$compile(e.srcElement)($scope);
```

`e.srcElement` is the DOM element I want to `$compile`.

I wonder, if there is any established way to check if a given DOM element has been compiled.

I know it's possible if I attach some data attributes to the DOM during compiling, and try to retrieve that later. What I want to know is if there is any existing method in AngularJS.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Within a directives compile function, parents have already been compiled. Children have not yet.  Siblings have been compiled if their priority number is greater than the current directive's priority:

```
   compile: function (element, attr){
           element.children(); // not compiled
           elements.parents(); // compiled
           elements.siblings(); // compiled if priority > current directive priority.  If same, then not defined.
   });
```

Comment: I think I'm not talking about the compile functions in directives, but manually called `$compile` service. Thanks!

Comment: Then the answer is no.